# Masonry Uncaught TypeError on appended

Tags: javascript, jquery, masonry

Here's the function I use to append items and relayout :

```
        var items = [$('<div class="item masonry-brick"><div class="picture"><a class="image" title="Title" href="#"><img alt="" src="./uploads/14.jpg"></a><div class="item-content"><div class="meta"><span><i class="icon-calendar"></i>09 Jan 2015</span></div></div></div></div>')];
        $container.append(items);
        $container.imagesLoaded(function() {
            $container.masonry('appended', items);
        });
```

The layout comes out properly, but the console shows :

```
Uncaught TypeError: .item is not a function
```

Here's the container init in case it helps :

```
var $container = $('#items');
$container.imagesLoaded(function() {
    $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: ".item",
        columnWidth: 290,
        isAnimated: true
    });
});
```

What's happening there?

Comment: Why are you wrapping jQuery object inside an array?

Comment: mmm, that's a leftover from some previous code, thx for spotting that!